# Breaking even: is there a point where you can always profit?

Tags: statistics

If say a tennis match is paying *7:1* on *Player X* and *2:1* on *Player Y* can I place certain amounts on each to break even? Or even profit? How can I calculate that?

**EDIT**

Sorry, *X* is playing *Y*.

Comment: So no matter which player wins, the house loses? Are player X and player Y playing against each other?

Comment: If you place \$100 on player X and \$100 on player Y, then you win \$700-\$200 = \$500 if player X wins and \$200-\$200=0 break even if player Y wins.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. Yeah, they're playing each other.

Comment: That must be a mistake, no betting agency would allow such a thing.

Comment: @Carlster You're right that no organized place would ever make that bet, but that doesn't mean this type of thing doesn't have real life applications. For instance, if you're betting with friends, each whom think different teams have different chances to win. You may get one friend to lay you odds on team $A$, and another friend to lay you even better odds on team $B$. You bet with both and automatically win.

Comment: Oh. I think my innocence just broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a sure profit, you can find a betting ratio that assures you a profit regardless of who wins.  Say you bet $1$ on $X$ and $y$ on $Y$.  If $X$ wins, you get $7$ back.  If $Y$ wins you get $2y$ back.  To make it so you don't care who wins, you want $7=2y, y=\frac 72$  Now for each $\frac 92$ you bet you get $7$.  Wow-over a $50\%$ return.  Bet all you can at this ratio.

The same approach works for different odds.  Find the ratio of bets that makes you indifferent to who wins.  If you win, bet all you can.  If you lose at this ratio, only bet if the market is wrong about the probabilities.  Maybe you know something the market doesn't know (this is called insider trading).  Maybe you know something is important that the market has overlooked-make a killing.

Comment: Where does the $9$ in $\frac 92$ come from? Is the numerator increased by the denominator's value?

Comment: @nononono $\frac{9}{2}=1+y=1+\frac{7}{2}$.

Comment: Then what is the significance of $1$? Just the multiplication factor of the ratio?